# python: add max() to a range variable based in previous column values

Tags: python, slice

I have just start with python, and I'm trying to do some practice trying basing in some excel files I use. So sorry If its a extrange/noob question :)

in dataframe (data2) I have 3 columns:

1. 'Data',
2. 'Start'(random value minor of current row position),
3. 'Finish' (basically a index location, -> data2['Finish'] = (data2.index)  )

I'm trying to add a column that shows the max value of 'Data' column for the range assigned regarding 'Start' and 'Finish'

I tried with no success

```
import numpy as np
data2 = pd.read(myfile.cvs)
data2['new_max_row'] = data2['Data']['Start':'Finish'].max()
```

if I change to so fixed numbers works

```
data2['new_max_row'] = data2['Data'][2:5].max()
```

also if I do with one number it works

```
data2['new_max_row'] = data2['Data'][2:'Finish'].max()
data2['new_max_row'] = data2['Data']['Start':5].max()
```

So I don't know if ':' between variables is a trouble

How can I make works:

```
 data2['new_max_row'] = data2['Data']['Start':'Finish'].max()
```

thanks in advance

I add an example table with examples about 3 current rows and the expected result

| Data | Start | Finish | new_max_row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 | 11 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 | 11 |
| 4 | 6 | 7 | 5 |

I'm trying a new approach  with islice (confirming data is integer)

```
 import numpy as np
 import itertools
 data2 = pd.read(myfile.cvs)

 data2['Start2'] = data2['Start'].astype('int64')
 data2['Finish2'] = data2['Finish'].astype('int64')

 data2['new_max_row'] = max(itertools.islice(data2['Data'], data2['Start2'], data2['Finish2']))
```

but I get this error:

```
 ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
 Input In [80], in <cell line: 2>()
 1 #data2['new_max_row'] = max(data2['Data'][slice(data2['Start2'], data2['Finish2'])])
 ----> 2 data2['new_max_row'] = max(itertools.islice(data2['Data'], data2['Start2'], data2['Finish2']))

 ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.
```

I tried Mohamed code, and after some errors it gives me a result with the following code

```
for i in range(len(data2)):
 data2['new_max_row'][i] = data2[:i+1]['Data'].max()
```

but it gives me the maximum from the begining, and not from the index in **'Start'** column.
I dont know how to add this variable before ':'

| Data | Start | Finish | new_max_row | desired_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 | 11 | 11 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 | 11 | 11 |
| 4 | 6 | 7 | 11 | 5 |

Comment: You describe the DataFrame, but don't provide an example of such a DataFrame, or share the code that shows how you construct it. Without knowing what your DataFrame actually looks like, answering your question is guesswork.

Comment: I add a table with the example

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the data and add the max value to the new column

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  df["new_max_row"][i] = df[:i+1].max("data")
```

I think this should work

Comment: the starting point is not based in information from the colum